# Obtaining 1-Way ANOVA tables for subsets in a list

Tags: anova

I have a list of dataframes and I want to apply a 1-Way ANOVA to each dataframe. Is this possible? I've tried using anonymous functions but I keep getting errors. Each dataframe consists of 3 columns. The first is the subject name, the second is the factor levels and the third is the response value. Here is some sample code to help with the solution.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = rep("Sean", 9), variable = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c")), value = rnorm(9, 11))
df2 <- data.frame(name = rep("Laura", 9), variable = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c")), value = rnorm(9, 44))


my_list <- list(df1, df2)
```

I understand that an lm model must be created for each dataframe `lm(value ~ variable, data = df` and then I can use the anova function on the models. However, I can't get the job done. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed to figure out a way of getting this done. I tried the following which gives me a list of ANOVA tables.

```
models <- lapply(my_list, function(l) { lm(l[[3]] ~ l[[2]], data = l) } )
anova_tabs <- lapply(models, function(m) { anova(m) })
```